# core at which function is running

Tags: embedded, linux-kernel, kernel, device-driver, smp

consider a kernel tasklet scheduled and executing the tasklet function.

Is there a way to know which core the tasklet is running ?
I mean is there a function / variable to know at which core the tasklet is running at.
Architecture is arm.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A tasklet will always run on the same processor core that scheduled it.  Inside the kernel, you can call `smp_processor_id()` to find out what processor you're currently running on.

Check /proc/cpuinfo for a mapping of processor number to physical id and core id.  Hyperthreading will create 2 logical processors for each core.

Answer (score 0):

See [man 7 cpuset](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/cpuset.7.html).

Comment: This isn't correct, as tasklets are not processes or threads.